# Google Search with Or condition

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to do a google search news with an OR condition. 
I have tried the following but not working "Test Car" + "Coffee" + "Pills"

So it should return me results in the news for Test Car Or Cofee or Pills.

I need to to it this way vs each one individually as the result I will feed into an application.

Comment: this would result in `Test CarCoffeePills` how do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
"Test Car" OR "Coffee" OR "Pills"
```

from:
http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861

Comment: That page refers to Google Search, not to Google App Engine.

Comment: I'm not convinced the questioner is asking about app-engine (despite the tag...)

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not directly support disjunction queries like this, because they cannot be executed any more efficiently by a query planner than by you. Instead, make 3 separate queries and merge the results (if needed).

Comment: The Search API does support boolean operators. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Boolean_Operators_and_Grouping